# Summing over spins in QED and calculating the square of Feynman amplitudes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, scattering, spinors, scattering-cross-section

I'm trying to compute the differential decay rate given by the following amplitude:

$$M = i g \bar{u}(q,s)\gamma^\mu \displaystyle{\not}\epsilon^\mu_r(p)v(\tilde{q},s')$$

which concerns the interaction of fermions with massive vector bosons ($\epsilon^\mu_r$ is the polarisation vectors for the bosons). The interacting Lagrangian for this process is given by: $g \bar{\psi}\displaystyle{\not}A\psi$, where $g$ is the coupling constant.

To compute the decay rate, I first need to compute the square of the amplitude and sum over the final state fermions.

This is my attempt:

$$|M|^2 = MM^\dagger = g^2[\bar{u}(q,s)\gamma^\mu \displaystyle{\not}\epsilon^\mu_r(p)v(\tilde{q},s')][\bar{v}(\tilde{q},s')\epsilon^\mu_r \gamma^\mu u(q,s)] $$

Then summing over spins we get and explictly writing spinor indices:

$$\sum_{s,s'} \{\bar{u}_\alpha(q,s) \gamma^{\mu}_{ab}v_b (\tilde{q},s')\bar{v}_{c}(\tilde{q},s') \gamma^\nu_{cd} u_d(q,s)\} \epsilon_\mu^r(p) \epsilon_\nu^r(p) \\
= \{[\displaystyle{\not}q + m]_{ad} \gamma^\mu_{ab}[\displaystyle{\not}\tilde{q}-m]_{bc} \gamma^\nu_{cd}\}\epsilon_\mu^r(p) \epsilon_\nu^r(p) \\
=Tr\{\gamma^\mu [\displaystyle{\not}q + m] \gamma^\nu[\displaystyle{\not}\tilde{q} - m]\} \epsilon_\mu^r(p) \epsilon_\nu^r(p)$$

Expanding the trace I would get:

$$Tr(\gamma^\mu \displaystyle{\not}p m \gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu \displaystyle{\not}p \gamma^\mu \displaystyle{\not} \tilde{p} - \gamma^\mu m^2 \gamma^\nu + \gamma^\mu m \gamma^\nu \displaystyle{\not}p)$$

I know how to evaluate the third term since that would simply be $4g^{\mu\nu} m^2$, but not sure how about the other terms. I know that the trace of three gamma matrices must vanish so my guess would be that the first and last terms vanish, however they contain three gamma matrices multplying $p_\mu$ so not sure if that is the case.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Trace_identities

Comment: Hint: write ${\not}p=p_\mu \gamma^\mu$, then use the fact that (from the point of view of the "spinor space" in which the $\gamma^\mu$ are 4 matrices) $p_\mu$ is a set of four scalars (not a matrix) so it can be pulled out of the trace.